# What's the point of hiding self-linking in comments?

Tags: seo, comments, hyperlink

On [this site](http://osxdaily.com/2011/12/30/exclude-drives-or-folders-from-spotlight-index-mac-os-x/), there are links of related articles as usual, and underneath, comments.

[image: Related articles]
[image: Comments]
Some of them are linking to the same kind of articles **on the same site**, but using false users with a personal URL pointing to it.

**What's the (SEO) point of this?**

It's worth noting that there's a [RSS feed](http://osxdaily.com/2011/12/30/exclude-drives-or-folders-from-spotlight-index-mac-os-x/feed/) for these comments.

Comment: This is a common spam technique of creating links in comment sections. One of the things a spammer will do is find sites and content that is related to their target page. There is automated software for this and these links appear in droves. G does not like these and if you do not police them on your own site, it will cost you some rank or could get you penalized.

Comment: @closetnoc Agreed, but in this case, the "spammer" is linking to the same site (osxdaily).

Comment: Well that would be just plain silly!! ;-) It could be the site owner spamming his own site. I am sorry I missed that detail. How funny is that??

Comment: They look like [linkback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linkback) type things. Note that the quotation is a direct quote of the surrounding text that contains a link back to this article. The timestamp of the "comment" is the date of the linked article. All very clever really since I assume this is automated. Although having them interspersed throughout the comments is confusing and a bad user experience IMO and there seems to be a considerable overlap with the "Related articles". The SEO-point would seem to be to just increase internal linkage but the UX is "uncomfortable" IMO.

Comment: Hang on, they appear to be `rel="external nofollow"` links - so I can't really see any point in them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are [pingbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pingback).

If post 1 links to post 2, a comment (including a link to post 1 as well as a quote) on post 2 gets posted¹, notifying the post author and the readers about the backlink.

You can verify it by looking at the HTML: each of these comments has the class `pingback`.

¹ This is likely happening automatically (many blog systems come with this functionality by default or as plugin).